# What do these errors in Event Viewer mean?

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer, error-logging

I have been getting a lot of Event ID 10 errors when starting up my Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit(SP1). Two errors (sources are WMI and Service Control Manager) are seen very often that on every start-up they occures(or at log on?):
[image]
( **The first two errors** )
Details from the General tab of the first error(i.e WMI) is given below:

> Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent
> WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND
> TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in
> namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot
> be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

And the details from the second one is:

> The NEWDRIVER service failed to start due to the following error:  The
> system cannot find the file specified.

Also, I am seeing a delayed log-on(do not know whether it is related)?
Do anyone know what these errors are and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 7):

**The WMI error is a known issue:**

From Microsoft's [KB2545227](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545227):

> Cause:
>
> This originated in the Windows 7 SP1 DVD/ISO creation process. There
>   was an issue in the creation process that caused a WMI registration to
>   remain in the DVD/ISO. Since the registration is designed to work only
>   during the DVD/ISO creation process, it fails to run on a live system
>   and causes these events. These events are not indicative of any issue
>   in the system and can be safely ignored. If however you want to
>   prevent these events from getting generated and want to remove this
>   specific WMI registration manually, please follow the steps mentioned
>   in this article for running the workaround script.

They offer a FixIt to fix the problem, plus manual instructions:

1. In Notepad create a new document named Workaround.txt
2. Copy the following script into notepad:

---

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\subscription")

Set obj1 = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from __eventfilter where name='BVTFilter' and query='SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ""Win32_Processor"" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99'")

For Each obj1elem in obj1

set obj2set = obj1elem.Associators_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

set obj3set = obj1elem.References_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

For each obj2 in obj2set

 WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

 WScript.echo obj2.GetObjectText_

 obj2.Delete_

next

For each obj3 in obj3set

 WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

 WScript.echo obj3.GetObjectText_

 obj3.Delete_

next

WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

WScript.echo obj1elem.GetObjectText_

obj1elem.Delete_

Next
```

3. Save the text as `Workaround.vbs`
4. Close Notepad
5. Open an elevated command prompt:

   a. Click on start

   b. Click on Programs

   c. Right-Click on Command Prompt

   d. Choose run as administrator
6. Change Directory to the one containing `workaround.vbs` (Example `CD c:\users\%username%`)
7. Run `cscript workaround.vbs`

After running the script the Event ID 10 errors related to this event should stop occurring. This does not remove any of the existing entries in the Event log, they would need to be manually cleared out of the application event log.

**For the "The NEWDRIVER service failed" issue:**

You have a service named "NEWDRIVER" registered with the system, but the file(s) it needs to run are missing.  Since the files are missing, and your computer is behaving OK, you can just remove the reference to the service.

You should be able to do this from an elevated command prompt, with the `sc` (Service Control) command. Eg.:

`sc delete NEWDRIVER`

Comment: Can I find which service was that?

Comment: I tried 'sc query newdriver' , it returns that **TYPE: 2 FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER**, **STATE: 1 STOPPED**, **WIN32_EXIT_CODE : 2 <0x2>, **SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0 <0x0>, **CHECKPOINT : 0x0 and **WAIT_HINT : 0x0**